# Connect remotely to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I've created a database using SQL Server Management Studio. I can see it on the same device the server is installed but can't see it when connecting to it via Studio. Any ideas where is the problem?

Comment: Please add more information about your setup to your question. What SQL server do you use? MySQL? What OS is running on your machine and the server and how do you try to connect to the remote server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Scrumdesk](http://www.scrumdesk.com/Articles/HowToEnableSQLServerRemoteConnections.html) has screen shots where you'll have to go into the SQL Configuration Manager and enable connections via TCP/IP and you should be good to go. By default this is turned off as it could be seen as a security risk.

From [How to configure SQL Express 2012 to accept remote connections](http://blog.citrix24.com/configure-sql-express-to-accept-remote-connections/) :

> To configure SQL Server 2012 Express to allow remote connections, you
>   must complete these steps:
>
> - Enable remote connections on the instance of SQL Server that you want
>     to connect to from a remote computer.
> - Configure SQL server to listen
>     on static port
> - Turn on the SQL Server Browser service.
> - Configure the
>     firewall to allow network traffic that is related to SQL Server and to
>     the SQL Server Browser service.